# javascript - insert a variable into regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following which works fine, allowing a form field to be valid if blank or containing the word "hello" or passing the other validation...

```
var re = new RegExp(/^$|^[hello]|^([FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/);
```

but I want to make the word "hello" be the value of a variable.

I have tried this but it no longer seems to work:

```
var i = "hello";
var re = new RegExp('/^$|^['+i+']|^([FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/');
```

Comment: Note that you're not checking for a string containing the word "hello" but rather it starting with the letters h,e,l or o.

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but you also need to escape your ` \ ` characters when you write your regex as a string, e.g., `\\d`.

Comment: Your regexp also matches the word `hyacinth`.

Comment: Instead of including the `^` and `$` in each option, you could just wrap the whole thing in parens: `/^(|hello|[FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/`. The fact that the `[]` around `hello` was doing the wrong thing has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your code.

- `RegExp` expects a **string**, not a regex literal like you pass in the first case. It seems that `RegExp` is smart enough though and detects that you are passing a regex literal. So your first example works by coincidence and is the same as:

  ```
  var re = /^$|^[hello]|^([FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/;
  ```
- The `/` are **not** part of the expression, they are the delimiters to denote a regex literal, much like quotation marks (`'`) indicate a string literal. Hence, if you pass the expression as string to `RegExp`, it should not contain `/`.
- Since the backslash is the escape character in strings as well, in order to create a literal backslash for the expression you have to escape it: `\\`.
- `[hello]` does not test for for the word `hello`, it matches either `h`, `e`, `l` or `o`, thus it is equivalent to `[ehlo]`.

With all that said, your code should be:

```
var i = "hello";
var re = new RegExp('^$|^'+i+'|^([FG]?\\d{5}|\\d{5}[AB])$');
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the leading and trailing `/` characters and your reg exp is not going what you expect. Double up the `\` characters so they are escaped. Also `[]` means match any of these characters.

Basic example

```
var str = "hello world";
var word = "hello"
var re = new RegExp("^" + word + "\\s?")
console.log( str.match(re) );
```